# Add text to TextField from an outside source

Tags: flutter, speech-recognition, textfield, flutter-layout

I added a speech recognition to a text field, it works but I cannot manage to add the text to the textfield, is there a way to do that.

the textfield looks like this:

```
  Widget _buildDescriptionTextField(productBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder<Object>(
        stream: productBloc.messageStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return TextField(
            maxLines: 3,
            controller: _controllerMessage,
            onChanged: productBloc.messageSink,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: allTranslations.text(StringConstant.description),
              errorText: snapshot.error,
              suffixIcon: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.mic), onPressed: () {
                if (_isAvailable && !_isListening)
                  _speechRecognition
                      .listen(locale: "en_US")
                      .then((result) => print('$result'));
              },
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

I have a steam-builder to manage the added text manually, and an controller if this page is used for editing, then as suffixsIcon the iconButton to start the speech recognition. when I add the result text outside a text Widget it works but I need it inside the texField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So What I did is just used the `_speechRecognition.setRecognitionResultHandler` from the documentation, to set a new value to the controller of the textField, like so:

```
    _speechRecognition.setRecognitionResultHandler(
          (String speech) => setState(() {
            _controllerMessage = new TextEditingController(text: resultText = speech);
          })
    );
```

the textField stays like it was before, see question.

Answer (score 1):

Just doing that should work no ?

```
setState(() => _controllerMessage.text = result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`TextEditingController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) properties. I assume you declared one as `_controllerMessage`.

To set new value to your `TextField` and keep the cursor in the end - use something similar to the example from the Docs.

e.g.

```dart
_speechRecognition
  .listen(locale: "en_US")
  .then(_onResult);

// ...

void _onResult(String result) {
  setState(() {
    _controllerMessage.value = _controllerMessage.value.copyWith(
      text: result,
      selection: TextSelection(baseOffset: result.length, extentOffset: result.length),
      composing: TextRange.empty,
    );
  });
}
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, I've made a simple app using this but still does not work, any other idea?

Comment: @key please see my updated answer. I completely neglected the use of ‘result’ variable. Let’s see if it works now.

Comment: could you have another look, after changing text.length i managed to remove all errors but it still doesn't work

Comment: I Solved it using the method from the documentation. but thank you very much for your help. I voted your answer up. see my answer